# how to break large excel sheet into multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have large amount of excel sheet where 16k records i want to break it into multiple sheets like in 2000 records in 1 excel sheets and if any think left so it should be add in next sheet please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance so much
Vijay Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much you know about VBA but you can use following codes to achieve your goal. I will post 2 options. First macro will delete the lines which copied from the source sheet, second macro will keep source sheet values. All you need to do is update the code with the name of your source worksheet and how many lines you want in each generated sheet.

**Update Items**

```
Set CWS = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Source Worksheet name
LineNo = 5 ' Number of lines in each sheet
```

**Macro 1: Will delete copied rows from source sheet.**

```
Dim CWS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim S_No As Long
Dim LineNo As Long

Set CWS = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Source Worksheet name
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LineNo = 5 ' Number of lines in each sheet including header
S_No = 1

i = 1
While i < LastRow
    CWS.Range("1:" & LineNo).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Partition " & S_No
    Sheets("Partition " & S_No).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    CWS.Range("2:" & LineNo).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    LastRow = CWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    S_No = S_No + 1
Wend
```

**Macro 2: Will keep copied rows in source sheet.**

```
Dim CWS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim S_No As Long
Dim LineNo As Long

Set CWS = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Source Worksheet name
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LineNo = 5  ' Number of lines in each sheet excluding header
S_No = 1

For i = 2 To LastRow
    CWS.Range("1:1," & i & ":" & i + LineNo - 1).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Partition " & S_No
    Sheets("Partition " & S_No).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    i = i + Sheets("Partition " & S_No).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    S_No = S_No + 1
Next
```

**UPDATE: I have updated the code to copy first row as a header to all sheets created. But please read the comment next to the `LineNo` variable.**

Comment: Thanks so much  for help I am a beginner for vba. i learn from home. Thanks again .

Comment: Thanks but still i have 1 doubt i need headings same for all sheets. thanks so much once again its really work.

Comment: @vijaybhatt hello, I have updated the code depending on your request. Now it will copy the first row as header to all pages.

Comment: how can i connect to you i need your more help in my another query.Thanks in advance